# OpenCV : rows not aligned after stereo rectification

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to rectify stereo images. I displayed 8 rows and 11 columns calibration pattern on my laptop and used the code from this github [repo](https://github.com/sdlouhy/StereoVision) to calibrate and rectify images.
As you can see on the 2 stereo pairs below, when I plot results of rectification (on chessboard images), rows are aligned in both sides, although it is not perfect.

[first stereo pair (calibration images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wzB9.jpg)

[second stereo pair (calibration images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzQuY.jpg)

Some information about calibration :

95 stereo pairs for calibration

```
Rotation Matrix [[ 0.9985 -0.0102 -0.0543]
 [ 0.0073  0.9986 -0.0531]
 [ 0.0547  0.0526  0.9971]]

K_left [[952.8207   0.     639.5   ]
 [  0.     952.8207 479.5   ]
 [  0.       0.       1.    ]]

K_right [[956.8061   0.     639.5   ]
 [  0.     956.8061 479.5   ]
 [  0.       0.       1.    ]]
```

Flags I used in stereoCalibrate :

```
flags = ( cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + cv2.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT
+ cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO  )
```

Flags I used in stereoRectify :

```
flags= cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, alpha = 0
```

Calibration images are 1280 x 960 (width x height)

Reprojection loss = 0.44 ( is it too high ? )

However, when I rectify new images (ie, not calibration images), rows from left and right images are not aligned :
[result of stereo rectification on new images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4usQ.png)

( **Remark** : "test" images are 960 x 540 but calibration images are 1280 x 960. This is because calibration images are photos taken with a GoPro in "photo mode", but "test" images are images from videos for which resolution differs. The  [following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfbhv.png) shows an image from a video (ie, a test image) in the foreground, and a calibration photo in the background. We can see the difference of resolution. To solve this issue, I added a black padding in each sides of video images to make them 1280 x 960, as calibration images. So the black corners are from images and not from any value of alpha in stereoCalibrate).

I don’t understand what is wrong. (The aformentionned reprojection error of 0.44 seems high to me, but I don’t know what should I change to get lower error. ). Do you know where could be the problem ? (calibration images, flags) ? Let me know if you need additionnal information.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Why does the image resolution between calibration and usage differ? 3 possible reasons for your results I see: 1. Capturing time of the 2 frames isnt identical (how do you trigger the cameras? Are they in any way synchronized?) 2. misplacement of the stereo setup due to mechanical forces (how do you make sure the setup doesnt deform?) 3. stereo calibration result isnt good enough, only works for a few calibration images but not over the whole space.

Comment: I remember those coefficients... related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/row-not-aligned-when-rectifying-images-with-stereorectify/9238

Comment: Ki @Micka. Thank you for your reply. I have just edited my post to explain why resolution differs between calibration and usage (in "Remark"). It's possible my stereo setup deforms, as it is embedded on a 1 x 0.6 meter remote car which is unstable. I'll try making the setup more stable and check point 1. in the same time. As for 3., do you say it is not good enough with respect to chessboard images ? I have checked multiple chessboard pair and alignment looks good to me. (Of course, on other images it's not, probably due to setup deformation)

Comment: "because calibration images are photos taken with a GoPro in "photo mode", but "test" images are images from videos for which resolution differs." Really use the same mode for calibration and processing! You should even switch off any vieeo stabilization and other stuff, since those basically break your calibration.

Comment: "1. in the same time. " What does that mean? Same time up to 1 microsecond or nanosecond or 15 milliseconds? This is very important!

Comment: Hi Micka, Thank you very much for your meaningful suggestions. Deformation of my setup between calibration and usage image was causing the issue. I took new calib images and usage videos and ensured to have a stable setup. Now the rows are perfectly aligned !