# Images after stereo rectification are not row aligned

Tags: python, opencv

**What the problem is:**
I have been following this tutorial ([Link](https://python.plainenglish.io/the-depth-i-stereo-calibration-and-rectification-24da7b0fb1e0)) as well as the openCV documentation but I cannot seem to get my stereo rectification right.

**How my problem is different:**
My setup is mechanically fixed, which was the issue in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72680293/opencv-rows-not-aligned-after-stereo-rectification) post.

**What I have done:**
Computed camera intrinsics and stereo parameters in MATLAB’s Camera Calibrator. Then followed said tutorial to undistort and rectify both stereo images. MATLAB’s Stereo Calibrator produces [this rectified image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5mj2.jpg) (which looks perfectly row-aligned) that I want to reproduce in python for the same images.

I am using six corners of a chessboard in the left frame and connecting them with a line to the corresponding corners in the right frame.
My idea is that epipolar lines must be horizontal in an undistorted and rectified image, so these connecting lines must be horizontal (average slope very close to 0). Yet they are not!

**How to get there:**

[left image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odp4A.jpg)
[right image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwshS.jpg)

```
    import cv2 as cv
    import numpy as np

    # Intrinsics from MATLAB
    distortionCoefficientsL = np.array([0.1112, -0.2270, 0.0014, 7.5801e-04, 0.0835])
    cameraMatrixL = np.array([[1384.3, 0, 933.5327], [0, 1383.2, 532.1460], [0, 0, 1]])
    newCameraMatrixL = cameraMatrixL

    distortionCoefficientsR = np.array([0.0362, -0.1640, -2.2236e-04, 3.4982e-04, 0.1148])
    cameraMatrixR = np.array([[1417.1, 0, 972.7481], [0, 1418.0, 542.9659], [0, 0, 1]])
    newCameraMatrixR = cameraMatrixR

    # Stereo params from MATLAB
    Rot = np.array([[0.9999, 0.0109, 0.0068],[-0.0111, 0.9998, 0.0178],[-0.0066, -0.0179, 0.9998]])
    Trns = np.array([[-96.5080], [-1.0640], [-0.8036]])
    Emat = np.array([[0.0015, 0.7844, -1.0782],[-0.1459, 1.7298, 96.4957],[0.0084, -96.4985, 1.7210]])
    Fmat = np.array([[7.8440e-10, 4.0019e-07, -9.7456e-04],[-7.4317e-08, 8.8188e-07, 0.0677],[4.5630e-05, -0.0706, 3.0555]])


    # Rectification and undistortion
    imgL = cv.imread(‘path to left image’)
    imgR = cv.imread(‘path to right image’)
    grayL = cv.cvtColor(imgL,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayR = cv.cvtColor(imgR,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    imgSize = grayL.shape[::-1]


    R_L, R_R, proj_mat_l, proj_mat_r, Q, roiL, roiR= cv.stereoRectify(newCameraMatrixL, distortionCoefficientsL, newCameraMatrixR, distortionCoefficientsR, imgSize, Rot, Trns, flags=cv.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, alpha=1)

    leftMapX, leftMapY = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(newCameraMatrixL, distortionCoefficientsL, R_L, proj_mat_l, imgSize, cv.CV_32FC1)
    rightMapX, rightMapY = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(newCameraMatrixR, distortionCoefficientsR, R_R, proj_mat_r, imgSize, cv.CV_32FC1)
    Left_rectified = cv.remap(imgL,leftMapX,leftMapY, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    Right_rectified = cv.remap(imgR,rightMapX,rightMapY, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT)

    grayL = cv.cvtColor(Left_rectified,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayR = cv.cvtColor(Right_rectified,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    fontScale = 4

    # Find all chessboard corners at subpixel accuracy
    boardSize = (6,9)
    subpix_criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 10e-06)
    winSize = (11,11)

    retL, cornersL = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayL, boardSize, cv.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
    retR, cornersR = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayR, boardSize, cv.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)

    objp = np.zeros((1, boardSize[0]*boardSize[1], 3), np.float32)
    objp[0,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:boardSize[0], 0:boardSize[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)
    objectPoints = []
    imagePointsL = [] 
    imagePointsR = [] 

    slopes = []
    if retR is True and retL is True:
     objectPoints.append(objp)
     cv.cornerSubPix(grayR, cornersR,(3,3),(-1,-1),subpix_criteria)
     cv.cornerSubPix(grayL, cornersL,(3,3),(-1,-1),subpix_criteria)
     imagePointsR.append(cornersR)
     imagePointsL.append(cornersL)
    
     # Get points in 4th row (vertical centre) and display them
     vis = np.concatenate((Left_rectified, Right_rectified), axis=1)
     for i in range(24,30):
         x_l = int(round(imagePointsL[0][i][0][0]))
         y_l = int(round(imagePointsL[0][i][0][1]))
         cv.circle(vis, (x_l, y_l), 7, (0,255,255), -1)
         x_r = int(round(imagePointsR[0][i][0][0]+Left_rectified.shape[1]))
         y_r = int(round(imagePointsR[0][i][0][1]))
         cv.circle(vis, (x_r, y_r), 7, (0,255,255), -1)
         slope = (y_l-y_r)/(x_r-x_l)
         slopes.append(slope)
         cv.line(vis, (x_l,y_l), (x_r,y_r), (0,255,255), 2)

     avg = sum(slopes)/len(slopes)
     cv.putText(vis, 'Average slope '+str(avg),(vis.shape[1]//3, (vis.shape[0]//5)*4), font, fontScale, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv.LINE_AA)
     cv.imshow('Rectification check - remapped images', vis)
    
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkvAJ.jpg) so it seems to me that something is wrong with the rotaton of one or both of the images

When I undistort both images individually and connect the six corresponding points I seem to get a better row-aligned view than with the rectification process so this might be prove that cameraMatrix, newCamMatrix & distCoeffs are good?!

Any help appreciated!!

**Edit:**
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otjqW.jpg) is another visual representation with horizontal lines instead of connecting lines between two corresponding points.

**Edit2:**
[Prove that MATLAB detected all corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiNvl.jpg)

[Prove that openCV detected all corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj3Wr.jpg)

Comment: Can you draw a few horizontal lines between both images?

Comment: @Micka, I added another image with horizontal lines to the bottom of my post

Comment: Those images were used for calibration/rectification? Can you check whether the checkerboard corners were detected correctly? Looks that even they mismatch by width of about 1 of the drawn lines

Comment: Yes, the exact two images were used in MATLAB for stereo calibration (individual camera calibration was done on different set of images) as well as in openCV. I have added a screenshot of the detected corners from MATLAB as well as openCV...

Comment: @Micka, sorry to bother you I'm new here and dont know whether you were notified about my latest comment. Have you got any idea what else I could try to fix the issue?

Comment: can you try to run the cameraCalibration with openCV too and compare the results to the matlab camera calibration? I dont know about possible differences.

Comment: does it make a differnce whether you use     boardSize = (6,9) or     boardSize = (9,6)?

Comment: @Micka, you saved my day. I have recalibrated my stereo setup in openCV (although I was told its less exact than MATLAB) using the same images that I used in MATLAB. The most notably different result was the stereo Translation matrix, which in openCV is ```Trns_openCV = [[-4.39292106],[-0.04104796],[-0.02731911]]``` while in MATLAB it was ```Trns_MATLAB = ([[-96.5080], [-1.0640], [-0.8036]]```. My squareSize is 22mm, which I defined in MATLAB but I didnt define any squareSize in openCV so I dont know how this happened...

Comment: that's the extrinsics-/stereo-calibration? Are the intrinsics similar to the Matlab computed intrinsics? It might be possible that Matlab indeed is more accurate but uses a different coordinate system or a different model for the camera distortion (or different order of the distortion parameters). So in the end, the pure raw values might not be compatible?

Comment: I think `Trns_openCV` and `Trns_MATLAB` and are mostly in a different scale (factor of 22 mm), which shouldnt be a problem I think, but I dont have enough experience with opencv stereo, so it's uncertain and thr 3rd parameter has a scale difference of factor 29 instead of 22, so that might really be the error.

Comment: I am still working on finding out the exact differences that caused the original issue. Ill make sure to update the post as soon as I find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably messed up with the rotation matrix. I did some test with [my code](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo/blob/master/examples/007%20UseRawCameraData.py) and obtained the same result (up to numerical precision).

It turns out that you probably inverted the rotation matrix during calibration.
By replacing:

```
Rot = np.array([[0.9999, 0.0109, 0.0068],[-0.0111, 0.9998, 0.0178],[-0.0066, -0.0179, 0.9998]])
```

with its transpose (= inverse for rotations) as:

```
Rot = np.array([[0.9999, 0.0109, 0.0068],[-0.0111, 0.9998, 0.0178],[-0.0066, -0.0179, 0.9998]]).T
```

You obtain the expected result.

[image]

Comment: yes you're right. I believe that the syntax for some matrices, such as the rotation matrix, is different in MATLAB and openCV. So simply copying a rotation matrix from MATLAB and using it in openCV without converting it to a transpose will lead to incorrect results. Thanks for your help!